# Why does my method not work for this probability question?

Tags: probability

Six distinct numbers are randomly distributed to players numbered 1 through 6.
Whenever two players compare their numbers, the one with the higher one is declared
the winner. Initially, players 1 and 2 compare their numbers; the winner then
compares her number with that of player 3, and so on. Let X denote the number of
times player 1 is a winner. Find P(X = i), i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

So the answer is that for each i we find the probability that it is the winning number and that it is less than the next number which should be the largest number.

so at i(0) = 1/2  (since it may be bigger than the next or smaller)

but at i(1)= 1/6. This is because of the three numbers there is a 1/3 chance of the next number being the largest, 1/2 chance of the number in question being the second largest.

All of this makes sense but why would I get the wrong answer with my logic?

beats first number = 1/2
loses to number after = 1/2

therefore, probability would be (1/2)(1/2) =  1/4

Could someone explain to me how I get this number by using my logic and where there is a flaw in my logic? Thanks.

Comment: See, the point is that player $1$ wins whenever he has the largest number out of all the six players in the game, because he has to win the comparison against all the five players. Since the numbers each one gets is independent of the others, the probability of $1$ winning the game is just $\frac{1}{6}$ by symmetry.

Comment: But if the numbers are distributed as, say, 3, 0, 2, 4, 5, 1, then player 1 wins twice before losing.

Comment: qaispak, think about a tree diagram.

Comment: What's the source of this problem?  It is nearly a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940616/combinatorics-probability-why-does-this-equation-work/1940642?noredirect=1#comment3984718_1940642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially saying that
$$
P(\text{1 beats 2, 1 loses to 3})=P(\text{1 beats 2})\cdot P(\text{1 loses to 3}).
$$
In other words, you're assuming that these events are independent.

However, that is not likely -- the fact that player 1 beats player 2 gives us information about player 1's number, and should therefore impact our belief that 1 will lose to 3.  (Namely, beating player 1 requires having a higher number, and therefore makes it less likely that player 1 will lose to player 3.)

Because these events aren't independent, you can't factor it this way; instead, you need to use the more generally true factorization
$$
P(\text{1 beats 2, 1 loses to 3})=P(\text{1 beats 2})\cdot P(\text{1 loses to 3}\mid \text{1 beats 2}).
$$

That is, you must use this factorization if you want to use a factorization at all.  I'd probably compute $P(X=1)$ by noting that players 1, 2, and 3 can have (as a whole) any three out of the six numbers; but, once we know which three numbers they have as a group, there's only one way to assign them to the players so that player 1 beats 2 but loses to 3 (namely, 2 must get the lowest, 1 the middle, and 3 the highest).  The remaining three numbers can be parceled out to players 4, 5, and 6 in any way.  So, 
$$
P(X=1)=\frac{\binom{6}{3}\cdot1\cdot3!}{6!}=\frac{1}{3!}=\frac{1}{6}.
$$
This argument can then be easily generalized to compute the probabilities of the remaining events $X=i$, $i=2,\ldots,6$.

Comment: I don't think I understood the formula you used, I will take some time to convince myself with that but the argument about independent/dependency makes sense to me. I suppose my knowledge of conditional probability is very weak right now